# How to replace a value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to group 23 different labels in second last column of ["KDDTest+.csv"](https://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/nsl.html)  into four groups. Please note, I have deleted the last column of the csv prior to doing this.

I have read the .csv file using

```
df = pd.read_csv('KDDTrain+.csv', header=None, names = col_names)
```

where

```
col_names = ["duration","protocol_type","service","flag","src_bytes",
    "dst_bytes","land","wrong_fragment","urgent","hot","num_failed_logins",
    "logged_in","num_compromised","root_shell","su_attempted","num_root",
    "num_file_creations","num_shells","num_access_files","num_outbound_cmds",
    "is_host_login","is_guest_login","count","srv_count","serror_rate",
    "srv_serror_rate","rerror_rate","srv_rerror_rate","same_srv_rate",
    "diff_srv_rate","srv_diff_host_rate","dst_host_count","dst_host_srv_count",
    "dst_host_same_srv_rate","dst_host_diff_srv_rate","dst_host_same_src_port_rate",
    "dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate","dst_host_serror_rate","dst_host_srv_serror_rate",
    "dst_host_rerror_rate","dst_host_srv_rerror_rate","label"]
```

If I print out the first 5 rows of the dataframe, this is the output (please note the 'label' column):

using `print(df.head(5))`

```
   duration protocol_type  ... dst_host_srv_rerror_rate    label
0         0           tcp  ...                     0.00   normal
1         0           udp  ...                     0.00   normal
2         0           tcp  ...                     0.00  neptune
3         0           tcp  ...                     0.01   normal
4         0           tcp  ...                     0.00   normal
```

I've tried both these methods for grouping based on what I found online:

Method 1:

```
df.replace(to_replace = ['ipsweep.', 'portsweep.', 'nmap.', 'satan.'], value = 'probe', inplace = True)
df.replace(to_replace = ['ftp_write.', 'guess_passwd.', 'imap.', 'multihop.', 'phf.', 'spy.', 'warezclient.', 'warezmaster.'], value = 'r2l', inplace = True)
df.replace(to_replace = ['buffer_overflow.', 'loadmodule.', 'perl.', 'rootkit.'], value = 'u2r', inplace = True)
df.replace(to_replace = ['back.', 'land.' , 'neptune.', 'pod.', 'smurf.', 'teardrop.'], value = 'dos', inplace = True)
```

Method 2:

```
df['label'] = df['label'].replace(['ipsweep.', 'portsweep.', 'nmap.', 'satan.'], 'probe',regex=True)
df['label'] = df['label'].replace(['ftp_write.', 'guess_passwd.', 'imap.', 'multihop.', 'phf.', 'spy.', 'warezclient.', 'warezmaster.'], 'r2l',regex=True)
df['label'] = df['label'].replace(['buffer_overflow.', 'loadmodule.', 'perl.', 'rootkit.'], 'u2r',regex=True)
df['label'] = df['label'].replace(['back.', 'land.' , 'neptune.', 'pod.', 'smurf.', 'teardrop.'], 'dos',regex=True)
```

However, this is still the output of printing the first 5 rows of the dataframe:

```
After replacing, first 5 rows of df: 

   duration protocol_type  ... dst_host_srv_rerror_rate    label
0         0           tcp  ...                     0.00   normal
1         0           udp  ...                     0.00   normal
2         0           tcp  ...                     0.00  neptune
3         0           tcp  ...                     0.01   normal
4         0           tcp  ...                     0.00   normal
```

I'm expecting the label column in row 2 to read 'dos' instead of 'neptune', but it's not happening.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `"neptune."` as the `to_replace` value with `regex = True`, you are telling Pandas to look for `"neptune"` and any single additional character (e.g., "neptuneX" or "neptune!"). Since that extra character is not present, the whole phrase does not get replaced. Instead you could use just `"neptune"`, or `"neptune.?"` for 0 or 1 extra characters, or `"neptune.*"` for 0 or any greater number of extra characters.

Without `regex = True`, you are telling Pandas to look for literal `"neptune."` phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using `"neptune."` instead of `"neptune"`

My tests seem to work with `"neptune"`

```py
>>> df
     label
0  neptune
>>> df["label"].replace(["neptune."], "normal", regex=True)
0    neptune
Name: label, dtype: object
>>> df["label"].replace(["neptune"], "normal", regex=True)
0    normal
Name: label, dtype: object
>>> df["label"].replace(["neptune"], "normal")
0    normal
Name: label, dtype: object
```

Comment: That worked, but I don't know why. Either way, thank you so much!